# Cache for only specific URLs with retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I need to cache response of only specific url addresses in my app; but what I found with many searches that I've done was cache with size limit for response;
Anyone knows a way to do caching for only specific urls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CacheControl for this https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cache/. Check the URL yourself and set it yourself before creating the call, or put the logic in an application interceptor.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .cacheControl(CacheControl.Builder()
      .noCache()
      .build())
    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .build();
```

https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/caching/

Comment: Hi!, the tutorial link is broken :(